# PHP fgets() not recognizing <?php

Tags: php, fgets

I am trying to parse the first few lines of a file however I just noticed, if the first line of the file is `"<?php"` it won't echo. However, if the first line of the file is "test" it will. Any ideas as to why?

```
<?php
$file= fopen("testfile.php", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
echo fgets($file);
fclose($file);  
?>
```

Comment: Because it's php code?!

Comment: Let me guess, you're viewing this in a browser, and not bothering to "view source"

Comment: Even if I view source it does not show the php tag

Comment: try using `<pre>...</pre>` tag and echo the file content between the tag.

Comment: Try an `echo "<pre>".file_get_contents("testfile.php")."</pre>";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you use a default content type `text/html`, hence `<?php` is recognised as an HTML tag and your browser doesn't display it. Check the source code of your page.

Here is a nice presentation how to do it: http://www.wikihow.com/View-Source-Code.

Comment: Clearly you know more about this than me or I wouldn't be asking. Was there an answer in your response? If not, could you elaborate?

Comment: @ShawnCooke Determining `<?php` as a HTML tag by your browser is the most obvious reason that comes to my mind. Browser can't interpret PHP code, neither as `fgets` can do any evaluation.

Comment: Even though the tag doesn't show, is it technically there? So instead of using echo to view it in the browser, if I wrote fgets($file) to a file, would it show?

Comment: @ShawnCooke `fgets` should *return* the value, which you are printing. So `fgets($file)` on its on won't do anything as long as you don't use any debugger. Try to use `var_dump` instead, it is more descriptive. Also you may check if `<?php` is literally the *first* line in your test file, keeping in mind possible line endings before it.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you! (Even with colors!)

```
highlight_file("testfile.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me is just not to echo the line to the browser. I really don't need it in the browser. In fact, I need other things from the file but just noticed that it was not able to be echo's so I thought I'd ask. Thanks to everyone for your help!